# Why doesn't the function work after I have changed the state in another component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Those are the three components I’m using, excluding the component that displays them in the DOM, but that’s not needed.

Here I have a Parent and two Child components.

For some reason when the popup is active, and I click the *Refresh Child 1 Component* button, it changes the state back to `Child1`, but I lose the functionality within that component. So the `popUpToggle` function stops working.

It was working fine before. When I click the *Refresh Child 1 Component* again however, it starts working. Why is that?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Child1 from './child1'
import Child2 from './child2'

const Parent = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState('');
  const [popUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [renderCount, setRenderCount] = useState(0);

  const popUpToggle = () => {
     setPopUp(!popUp)
     console.log('PopUp Toggle ran')
  };

  const reRenderComponent= () => {
     setRenderCount(renderCount + 1);
     setDisplay(
       <Child1 
         key={renderCount} 
         popUpToggle={popUpToggle} 
         renderCount={renderCount}
       />
     );
     popUpToggle();
     console.log('reRenderComponent ran, and the key is ' + renderCount)
  };
    
  useEffect(() => {
     setDisplay(
       <Child1 
         key={renderCount} 
         popUpToggle={popUpToggle} 
         renderCount={renderCount}
       />
     );
  }, [])

  return ( 
    <div>
      <button 
        style={{position: 'fixed', zIndex: '999', right: '0'}} 
        onClick={reRenderComponent}
      >
        Refresh Child 1 Component
      </button>
      {popUp ? <Child2 popUpToggle={popUpToggle}/> : null}
      {display}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Child 1:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Child1 = ({ popUpToggle, renderCount }) => {    
  return ( 
    <>
      <button onClick={popUpToggle}>
        Pop Up Toggle function
      </button>
      <h1>Child 1 is up, count is {renderCount}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Child1;
```

Child 2:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Child2 = ({ popUpToggle }) => {   
  return ( 
    <div 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .7)',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
        margin: '0',
      }}
    >
      <h1>Child 2 is up</h1>
      <h2>PopUp active</h2>
      <button onClick={popUpToggle}>Toggle Pop Up</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setDisplay(<Child1 /*etc*/ />);
```

Putting elements into state is usually not a good idea. It makes it very easy to cause bugs exactly like the one you're seeing. An element in state never gets updated, unless you explicitly do so, so it can easily refer to stale data. In your case, i think the issue is that the child component has a stale reference to `popUpToggle`, which in turn has an old instance of `popUp` in its closure.

The better approach, and the standard one, is for your state to contain just the minimal data. The elements get created when rendering, based on the data. That way, the elements are always in sync with the latest data.

In your case it looks like all the data already exists, so we don't need to add any new state variables:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [popUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [renderCount, setRenderCount] = useState(0);

  const popUpToggle = () => {
    setPopUp(prev => !prev);
  };

  const reRenderComponent = () => {
    setRenderCount(prev => prev + 1);
    popUpToggle();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{ position: "fixed", zIndex: "999", right: "0" }}
        onClick={reRenderComponent}
      >
        Refresh Child 1 Component
      </button>
      {popUp && <Child2 popUpToggle={popUpToggle} />}
      <Child1
        key={renderCount}
        popUpToggle={popUpToggle}
        renderCount={renderCount}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh ok, I thought there might have been an issue with my logic somewhere...it's still a logic issue but not what I thought it would have been. Thank you for helping me.